# Center ThreeJS PlaneHelper on geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, clipping, plane, ifc

I am using local clipping to allow my users to drop clipping planes on my models. When they add a clipping plane, I'm using `PlaneHelper` to visualize where the plane is. I cannot seem to get the PlaneHelper to be centered on my models. It always appears to be centered round `(0,0,0)`. My models are loaded from an external source, so I cannot assume they are always centered in the middle of the scene. Most the the ThreeJS examples involve a model that exists at the center of the scene, so the PlaneHelper just works without having to move it anywhere. ([Example 1](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping.html), [Example 2](https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_clipping_stencil.html)).

Here's what it looks like when I add the PlaneHelper:
[image: Plane not centered on model]

I would like the PlaneHelper to be centered around the model (mocked up in MS Paint):
[image: Desired plane position]

I create the `Plane` and `PlaneHelper` like so:

```
//helper function to calculate the center of the model I'm adding a clipping plane to
const center = this.getCenter(this.models[0]);

//helper function to determine how big the PlaneHelper is supposed to be
const size = this.getMaxDimension(this.models[0]);

//Create a plane along the X axis, centered on the model, along with something to visualize the plane
const localPlane = new THREE.Plane(new Vector3(1, 0, 0), -center.x);
const helper = new THREE.PlaneHelper( localPlane, size * 2, 0xFF0000 );    
this.scene.add(helper);

//Add the plane to my my model
this.models[0].material.forEach((m: Material) => {
    if(!m.clippingPlanes){
        m.clippingPlanes = [localPlane];
    } else {
        m.clippingPlanes.push(localPlane);
    }
});
```

As you can see in the first image, the `PlaneHelper` isn't centered on the model. If I try to set the position of the PlaneHelper, I can see the tail of the PlaneHelper correctly at the center of the model, but the actual plane takes on a weird angle and doesn't actually move.

```
helper.position.copy(center);
```

[image: Position appears correct, but plane is angled oddly]

What is the correct way to "shift" the `PlaneHelper` so that it's centered on my model?

Comment: The `PlaneHelper` always forces its `position` to (0, 0, 0).  See [this line](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/helpers/PlaneHelper.js#L40) in the source code.  You may want to take that source file and create your own `PlaneHelper` that doesn't do that (or just monkey patch the object or its prototype at runtime).

Comment: I've taken a go at this. I'm very much new to the math behind all this and somethings are throwing me for a loop. I can't simply copy/paste this class and change that line where the position is hard-coded to the center of my object. I can see they're initializing the object in the constructor with some positions - they're not typical `Vector3` objects though. I'm not familiar with them, but I think they're positions represented in a way that's more optimal for the GPU?

Comment: The other thing I do not understand is why setting the `position` of the `PlaneHelper` _after_ the plane has moved has the weird behavior. I'd expect the center of the plane move.